# Synch data between tabs -- google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to synch data between tabs, I have a gantt chart on my MAIN tab with multiple months and want to make a separate tab for each month. Ex. JUNE will have only the June section of the gantt chart zoomed in (by column size, etc.) and whatever I change in JUNE will populate MAIN and whatever I change on MAIN (as long as it's the right month) will populate JUNE.

I am using ArrayFormula right now but it only mirrors MAIN.

Thank you!

Comment: If all tabs are in the same spreadsheet, you can use filter and display the chart on each individual monthly tab.

Comment: @MikeSteelson thanks you! but for some reason it doesn't let me edit it on JUNE only mirrors from MAIN as well. Is it possible to edit on both tabs and they synch?

Comment: @MikeSteelson here is the example sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_1pc3PTHoeyDQI6ZZAZBMKchmQWeBDii6VZktktdgjk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought the diagram was drawn from a database and not directly on merged boxes if needed. The only simple solution I see is to group the columns and have them appear as needed. See test tab.